# GE PowerMark Gold + Conversion Kit

Tags: electrical-panel

GE has their PowerMark Gold series subpanels. Some of those are main lug that are convertible to main breaker.

I bought one of those panels

(https://www.lowes.com/pd/GE-125-Amp-14-Spaces-24-Circuit-Convertible-Main-Breaker-Panel-Load-Center/1091073?cm_mmc=shp--c--prd--elc--google--lia--206--switchgear--1091073-_-0&placeholder=null&&ds_a_cid=112741100&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5JKbiYKZ7QIVir3ACh3W0gu2EAQYByABEgJ_2fD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

It does have the instructions for hooking up a back feed breaker in the upper right slot but doesn’t say how to configure with a separate kit.

(https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-PowerMark-Gold-125-Amp-2-Pole-Main-Circuit-Breaker-Conversion-Kit-THQMH125CP/100118346).

The kit also doesn’t say anything about the breaker panel cover.

The breaker cover panel does not have a knock out for that. Am I supposed to cut an opening for it or are these conversion kits not compatible?

Is cutting the breaker cover allowed by code?[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I think that’s an old pic. The upper right corner method is just using two of the typical breaker spaces. 

Where it appears that there should be a breakout there isn’t one. Some of the other stores that sell the same box have clearer pics without a knockout. 

I could still be mistaken as the box I bought has a Pic suffix and there appears to be some listings without the ‘P’

Comment: Edit ‘P’ suffix

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of your panel's door please?

Comment: I’m trying to maximize future space. If I can use the adapter kit that appears to be located like a conventional main breaker then I gain back two spaces. 

Even in photos of covers that show a spot for a main, the space does not appear to be a knock out but instead just an indentation. https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-PowerMark-Gold-125-Amp-8-Space-16-Circuit-Outdoor-Main-Lug-Load-Center-TLM812RCU2P/100155884

Comment: That adapter kit appears to attach to the two top lugs (? Not sure of the term). Yeah? If that kit is not for boxes like mine I can’t figure what they are for except possibly legacy boxes. But even then I can’t find anything on the net about them.

Comment: For about $60 more, you can get a GE 200 amp panel with 40 spaces and and several breakers included - which makes up for much of the price difference.

Comment: Is there any downside to going with a 200 amp panel other than perhaps having to abandon the 200 breaker that comes with it and using a 100 amp in its place?

Comment: @Gregory -- is this panel going to be a main panel or a subpanel?

Comment: Subpanel. Main is 200 amp. I’d like this to be 240v/ 100 amp.

Comment: Will be feeding it with about 60’ of #3 Copper underground THWN.

Comment: Then you'll have a 100 Amp breaker in the main panel on the feed wire to this subpanel? If so, the breaker here can be **any** size. Smaller than 100 Amp would be a waste (but no harm done). Larger than 100 Amp is fine because the breaker in the main panel protects the wires.

Comment: Yes I had planned on 100 amp on both ends. I was under the impression they needed to match. If not, great!

Comment: So the main on the subpanel is only acting as a shutoff; it’s not providing any protection other than that?

Comment: Exactly! And if they were the same you would have to flip a coin to see which would trip first...

Comment: Y’all have been great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to use a backfed main with a THQLRK3 hold-down...

Your panel, unfortunately, is not compatible with the TQMH000 main breaker adapter kit you are contemplating.  This is denoted on the diagram by the box labeled "MAIN" taking up two branch breaker spaces, instead of being above the branch breaker "stack".

### ...or just get a larger panel

However, there's an easy way to forestall all this, and that's simply to take the panel back and get something chunkier.  Going up to a 24-space, 125A or even a 30- or 40-space panel isn't *that* much more expensive, and means you don't have to agonize over panel spaces nearly as much.  You won't need to replace the main breaker in the bigger panel, either, since you're fitting a subpanel.  (It's either an easy way to get the required shutoff means for a subpanel in an outbuilding, or can simply be replaced by main lugs if the subpanel is in the same building as the panel feeding it.)

Comment: This is great. I was operating under the assumption that 1) I needed to match breaker size and 2) that it may be less desirable to use a 150 or 200 or whatever larger panel. It sounds like both of those assumptions are incorrect. I have no problem spending an additional $63.75 to make this easier. So I’ll just return these and look for a main breaker panel with a 100+ amp rating with 20 or maybe 118 spaces. Grin.

Comment: @Gregory -- eheheh.  the PowerMark line goes up to 42 spaces because GE is silly and hasn't quite caught up to a 12-year-old code change.  (Other makes do better -- Siemens goes up to 54 spaces, while Eaton and Square-D both go up to 60)

Comment: And it won't even really be $63.75 because you get a few "free" breakers.